# how to remove duplicate nodes from treeview and merge its item to remaining treeNode (VB.net / C#)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, treeview

I want to Remove the duplicate Nodes from a treeview and merge its data into the remaining TreeNode . 
I am creating a windows application, all components are serverside component

```
Dim ParentTable As DataTable
     ParentTable = ds.Tables(0)
     Dim parentnode As TreeNode
        parentnode = New TreeNode("Tasks")
                    TreeView1.Nodes.Add(parentnode)
                    Dim MyTasks, Projects, Personal, Team As TreeNode
                    MyTasks = parentnode.Nodes.Add("My Tasks")
                    Projects = parentnode.Nodes.Add("Projects")
                    Personal = parentnode.Nodes.Add("Personal")
                    Team = parentnode.Nodes.Add("Team")
                    Dim Subparentnode As TreeNode
                    Dim childrow As DataRow
                    Dim childnode As TreeNode

                    For Each parentrow In ParentTable.Rows
                        Subparentnode = New TreeNode(parentrow.Item(12))
                        MyTasks.Nodes.Add(Subparentnode)
                        childnode = New TreeNode()
                    Next

                For Each parentrow In ParentTable.Rows
                    If (parentrow.Item(3) = 0 And parentrow.Item(4) = 0) Then
                        Subparentnode = New TreeNode(parentrow.Item(12))
                        Personal.Nodes.Add(Subparentnode)
                    End If


                    If Not (parentrow.Item(3) = 0 And parentrow.Item(4) = 0) Then
                        If Not (parentrow.Item(11) = "") Then
                            Dim isNotExists As Boolean
                            Dim node As New TreeNode
                            Dim SubparentnodeProjectName As TreeNode
                            SubparentnodeProjectName = New TreeNode(parentrow.Item(11))
                                                                                            Projects.Nodes.Add(SubparentnodeProjectName)
                                Subparentnode = New TreeNode(parentrow.Item(12))
                                SubparentnodeProjectName.Nodes.Add(Subparentnode)

                        End If
                    End If

            If (parentrow.Item(3) = 0 And Not parentrow.Item(4) = 0) Then
                Dim SubparentnodeProjectName As TreeNode
                SubparentnodeProjectName = New TreeNode(parentrow.Item(17))
                Team.Nodes.Add(SubparentnodeProjectName)
                Subparentnode = New TreeNode(parentrow.Item(12))
                SubparentnodeProjectName.Nodes.Add(Subparentnode)

            End If
                Next
            End If
```

c# code is also acceptable

I have Removed The Duplicate Nodes now but not able to merge the child of the duplicate . Can any body help me !

Please Provide some Code

Any help is greatly admired

Thanks you

Udit Bhardwaj[image: Uploaded Image]

Comment: are you using MVVM or code behind?

Comment: @pushpraj i am using core VB

Comment: what is the depth of comparison? 1 level 2 level? or just at given level?

Comment: just according to the given level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the description and comments i could propose a method to find if there is an existing  node or create a new one if not.

```
Function GetOrCreateTreeNode(root As TreeNode, newNodeName As String) As TreeNode
    For Each node As TreeNode In root.Nodes
        If node.Test = newNodeName Then
            Return node
        End If
    Next
    Dim newNode As TreeNode = New TreeNode(newNodeName)
    root.Nodes.Add(newNode)
    Return newNode
End Function
```

and example for usage goes like this

```
        If (parentrow.Item(3) = 0 And Not parentrow.Item(4) = 0) Then
            Dim SubparentnodeProjectName As TreeNode
            'use the method to find existing node of the given name or create a new one if does not exists'
            SubparentnodeProjectName = GetOrCreateTreeNode(Team.LastNode, parentrow.Item(17))
            Subparentnode = New TreeNode(parentrow.Item(12))
            SubparentnodeProjectName.Nodes.Add(Subparentnode)
        End If
```

I assume above method is to add team nodes, you can use it for projects in the same manner.

Comment: ty for the help let me try this ... thanx for giving your time

Comment: it is not working ,trying to make it more correct according to my need, it is not removing the duplicate nodes .

Comment: Since I could not test with your data, I did it with string values only. sample is just an attempt to meet your needs. I believe it is at least a kick start for your duplicate issue solution.

Comment: Use Text instead of name, i pasted the incorrect one. apologies for same.

Comment: i have removed the duplicates could you help me to merge the child of the removed node

Comment: the function would return the existing node, so if you add the child to it should merge them in one. btw after you remove the duplicates where you add the child nodes for it? you may add them to the previous one. or you may add all the nodes from the removed duplicate node to the one you keep. is it possible for you to share a working sample code for a better visibility.

Comment: THanks Alot bhai ur Code Helped me Alot To merge Duplicate
I Took the last node(parent) and added the child in it See

 SubparentnodeProjectName = GetOrCreateTreeNode(Team.LastNode, parentrow.Item(12))